# Changing DOM isn't being reflected in the document's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following line of JavaScript code:

```
divElement.childNodes[x].style[s] = rule.style[s];
```

Prior to this line being executed

```
divElement.childNodes[x].outerHTML
```

looks like:

```
"<SPAN id=sp_100 class=FolderNode>Root Folder</SPAN>"
```

and

```
document.getElementById("sp_100").outerHTML
```

looks like:

```
"<SPAN id=sp_100 class=FolderNode>Root Folder</SPAN>"
```

i.e. They match.

After that line of code gets executed, I see:

```
divElement.childNodes[x].outerHTML
```

looks like:

```
"<SPAN id=sp_100 class=FolderNode style=\"FONT-SIZE: 11px\">Root Folder</SPAN>"
```

and

```
document.getElementById("sp_100").outerHTML
```

looks like:

```
"<SPAN id=sp_100 class=FolderNode>Root Folder</SPAN>"
```

Any idea how the html isn't being updated?

When I step through an older version of the same code, I see it get updated.  The older version gets built with Synchronous JavaScript calls, the new version gets built with Asynchronous calls.

-Eric

Comment: Please post the whole code. It's doing something that's disconnecting the `divElement` from the DOM, so the two expressions are accessing different elements.

Comment: I might not be the only one but the actual code would greatly help.

Comment: Have you tried getting the object's reference with `getElementByID` and updating that object, instead of accessing the child nodes directly?

Comment: it sounds like you run the sweep before all the elements are in your dom after the async call.

Comment: It's funny that we all have the same programming language to describe logical constructs but still fall back to using "looks like" or "prior to this line gets executed" phrases.

Comment: That's how I'm going to give code snippets in answers from now on:

variable e is equal to new regular expression object passed the arguments string dot plus backslash forwardslash and string g

Comment: after this line variable e looks at varbale s very hard and realizes there is a path expression hidden inside it. Nervously he returns his match to the calling function.

Comment: Then variable e realize that its block finish executing and that it would meet its end at the hand of the infamous garbage-collector. Knowing that s would keep its value alive e disapeared into the void.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing a way to flag @arielnmz as the answerer, but he came the closest.  It's the approach that I'm taking.  In my asynchronous callback I'm passing the tree something like this (this is a tree):  `var myVar = MyCallBack(this);`  Inside my callback, I'm accessing the this that's in my closure as that, wondering if that could have disconnected it from the DOM, but the callback isn't in my stack when I'm seeing the weird behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the element's ID, I recommend you to always get an object's reference with the `getElementById` function. You can also use a reference to an object by directly using its id (I'm not sure it this is supported on all browsers).

Example:

```
obj = document.getElementById("Obj_id")
obj.style = "..."
```

Would be the same as:

```
Obj_id.style = "..."
```